# How to use Group by clause without model's id in Django ORM?

Tags: django

This is my Model

```py
class Model1(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

I want to get count of `category`. So I wrote ORM like below:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

result = Model1.objects.values('category').annotate(Count('sns_type'))
```

but the result shown like below

```py
<QuerySet [{'category': 'A', 'category__count': 1}, 
{'category': 'B', 'category__count': 1},...]>
```

I felt so weird, so I printed a query of this result.
query shown like below

```sql
SELECT "example_table"."category", COUNT("example_table"."category") AS "category__count" 
FROM "example_table" 
GROUP BY "example_table"."category", "example_table"."id"
```

I don't know Why `id` is included in this query.

Query I want to use is like below:

```
SELECT "example_table"."category", COUNT("example_table"."category") AS "category__count" 
FROM "example_table" 
GROUP BY "example_table"."category"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`.order_by(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Count

result = Model1.objects.values('category').annotate(
    Count('sns_type')
).order_by('category')
```

That being said, repeating the same category as a `CharField` is usually *not* a good idea. Usually one works with a `ForeignKey` to a `Category` model as part of [*database normalization* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class Model1(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Then you query with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(model1_count=Count('model1'))
```